# Script to pull Tickr using Cusip# on Vanguard - sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't. Why?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm a beginner and I wrote a script to pull the tickr symbol using the cusip number and I chose the Vanguard site to get the data. Didn't make any progress with requests and found a q here that it is a dynamic website and won´t be able to use requests.

Tried selenium instead using instructions from the web and while I had problems finding the right selector, eventually it ran. Now it works and sometimes it doesn`t. What is the reason for that? Here's my code. I want to run it with 70 items, not only 2...

```
#! python 3
# Tickr_Finder - a script to pull the tickr for a cusip

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By 
import time 

# add CUSIP list here:
list = ("02079K107","G46188101")

output = []
browser = webdriver.Chrome()

# pulling data from the link and storing it in the output variable:
for i in list:
    url = "https://investor.vanguard.com/search?query=037833100#q="+str(i)
    print("printing url ", url)
    browser.get(url)
        
    # copy TICKR
    element = browser.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,"ticker-title")
    tkr = element.text
    tkr_list = tkr.split("-")
    tickr = tkr_list[0]
    name = tkr_list[1]
    output.append({'tickr': tickr, 'name': name, 'cusip': i})
    time.sleep(3)

browser.close()
browser.quit()

for i in range(len(output)):
    print(i, output[i])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the page loading is slowly, so you should using **WebDriverWait** to wait until the element can be found before doing something.

view the document https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/waits/#expected-conditions

https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/waits/

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(lambda d: d.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,"ticker-title"))
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_selected((By.CLASS_NAME, "ticker-title")))
element = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,"ticker-title")
```

Comment: thank you. I hope I added the code at the right spots, but I get an error message: AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'is_selected'

Comment: I removed the second line of WebDriverWait... and only kept the one with lambda - now it runs :) Thanks so much for your help.